# Cannot convert jupyter notebook to pdf

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I get the following error when  I try to convert jupyter notebook to pdf. 
[image]
I'd appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? **Have you followed the suggestions in the error message?** Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, you need to install xelatex and add it to your path so that the conversion can take place.

Can you follow the instruction [here](http://www.texts.io/support/0002/) to install xelatex onto your system. Once done check in your cmd line that it is installed by doing the following,

```
latex --version
```

If this shows the version then it should work fine.

**Edit:**

Working Solution:

Ok. Thank you so much. It worked. I downloaded MikTex from (miktex.org/download). I made sure it is on the same path. Ran your command 'xetex --version' to make sure it's in the same path. Went back to jupyter notebook and was able to convert it to pdf. Thank you.

Possible Solution:

Go [here](https://jupyter.org/try) go to 'JupyterLab' which will allow you to open jupyter notebooks. Once opened( it is slow, so be patient) open your local file and then simply export it to pdf. This will not require any dependencies like on local side.

Comment: That's weird, I didn't expect that. The problem you are facing may be too broad and we can try a ton of solutions  and one would work. But, if you just want to export from jupyter notebook to pdf, why don't you use the online version. See my Updated answer

Comment: Try installing [MikTex](https://miktex.org/download) which will include Xelatex and once again ensure that it is added to your path. If you can then do                                  ```xetex --version``` and if it shows the version then it should work.

Comment: Opening JupyterLab online does take some time, depending on usage. I am unsure why it's opening up with a blank page on edge when you convert it. Are you sure that's not the output of the file that you converted?

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much. It worked. I downloaded MikTex from (https://miktex.org/download). Made sure it is in the same path. Ran your command 'xetex --version' to make sure it's in the same path. Went back to jupyter notebook and was able to convert it to pdf. Thank you.

Comment: if this answer helped solve your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex
```

will probably fix your issue

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I get invalid syntax error.

Comment: You're supposed to type this in your linux terminal

Comment: I use windows. My system says it doesn't recognize the command.